# How to change the height of the a WPF `<Separator />`?

Tags: wpf, xaml, menu, styles, height

I use the wpf  in a list menuitems in a normal menu (not the context menu).

Using the following style, the separator is not drawn:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="2" />
</Style>
```

The value of Height must *at least be 12,* but then the distance from menuitems is too large.

What is happening here? Is it logical? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 8):

Simply scale the separator on the Y axis

```
 <Separator>
    <Separator.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="3" />
     </Separator.RenderTransform>
 </Separator>
```

This will set the separator's height to 3 times the original one.

see this: [How to: Scale an Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-scale-an-element)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Margin` property to size and/or space the `Separator` element to a degree:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Width="100" Content="Click me" />
    <Separator Margin="50,20" />
    <Button Width="100" Content="Click me too" />
</StackPanel>
```

In general, its length will fill the available area, while its width will remain at one pixel, or vice versa depending on its orientation. This will affect its `Width`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Width="100" Content="Click me" />
    <Separator Margin="20" Width="20" />
    <Button Width="100" Content="Click me too" />
</StackPanel>
```

This won't affect the `Height` of the line in this orientation, but it *will* affect the total space that it takes:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Width="100" Content="Click me" />
    <Separator Margin="20" Height="50" />
    <Button Width="100" Content="Click me too" />
</StackPanel>
```

If you want more control over the line, then I would recommend that you use the [`Line` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.line.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use negative margin:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-4,0,-3,0" />
</Style>
```